# Rendering Header with react-virtuoso and material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tableheader, react-virtuoso

I switched my table to a virtuoso table to help with loading time. And I am having trouble having it format my table properly. The table was perfectly aligned before when it was only a material ui table. Ive read over the documentation and tried rendering my header using the fixedHeaderContent property inside my virtuoso table Ive also tried passing it as apart of the table components but nothing seems to work for formatting the table properly. Passing as a component is the only way i can get it to render at all.
Im hoping someones run into this problem before?

Heres how Im rendering the header now:

```
 const renderHeader = () => {
    return (
      <TableHead
        ref={ref}
        style={{
          position: 'sticky',
          top: 0,
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
        }}>
        <TableRow>
          {columns.map(cols => (
            <TableCell key={cols.id} className={classes.tableCell}>
              <div className={classes.tableHeadCell}>
                <span className={classes.tableHeadLabel}>{cols.label}</span>
                {cols.sortable && (
                  <Sorting
                    sortDirection={sortDirection}
                    sortName={sortName}
                    handleClick={handleSort}
                  />
                )}
              </div>
            </TableCell>
          ))}
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
    );
  });

return(
<Virtuoso
        ref={virtuoso}
        style={{ width: '100%', height: TABLE_HEIGHT, 
        backgroundColor: '#fff' }}
        components={{ Header: renderHeader }}
        data={pipelineItems}
        itemContent={renderRows}
       
      />
)
```

This is the only way Ive been able to get this header to render. However it does not seem to be associated with the table rows in the table body because they're not lining up with each other. The header is way shorter than the body horizontally.

I also tried using the fixedHeaderContent and inserting the table head code inside of there. But this renders nothing, and I get a warning in the console that says React does not recognize the `fixedHeaderContent` prop on a DOM element.

```
fixedHeaderContent={() => {
return (
      <TableRow>
          {columns.map(cols => (
            <TableCell key={cols.id} className={classes.tableCell}>
              <div className={classes.tableHeadCell}>
                <span className={classes.tableHeadLabel}>{cols.label}</span>
                {cols.sortable && (
                  <Sorting
                    col={cols.id === 'price' ? 'basePrice' : cols.id}
                    classes={classes}
                    sortDirection={sortDirection}
                    sortName={sortName}
                    handleClick={handleSort}
                  />
                )}
              </div>
            </TableCell>
          ))}
        </TableRow>
    )
}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be amazing.
[I am using react-virtuoso version 4.2.1 for reference](https://virtuoso.dev/mui-table-virtual-scroll/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a const with the name fixedHeaderContent returning the TableHead, then you have to pass this const into the fixedHeaderContent prop.
It will work

Comment: Example code would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Without `fixedHeaderContent`, the header isn't rendered.
Your implementation should remove `<TableHead>` from `renderHeader`.
Then, you would pass `renderHeader` into the `fixedHeaderContent` prop.

In my case, I did this:

```js
const TableComponents = {
  Scroller: forwardRef((props, ref) => <TableContainer {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Table,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TableBody: forwardRef((props, ref) => <TableBody {...props} ref={ref} />),
}
const fixedHeaderContent = () => <TableRow>...List of TableCell...</TableRow>
const itemContent = (index, row) => <>...List of TableCell...</>

return <TableVirtuoso
  style={{ height: 700 }} // Height is important!
  data={rows}
  totalCount={totalRows}
  components={TableComponents}
  fixedHeaderContent={fixedHeaderContent}
  itemContent={itemContent} />
```

For more details:
https://virtuoso.dev/mui-table-virtual-scroll/#material-ui-table-virtualized-with-table-virtuoso